# <a> style - fade link color on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

There are several links inside of a ul with a nicely looking css color transition on mouseover (a:hover).

1. How can I have an anchor to fade its color back to #374659 when the user clicks **another** link?
2. Additionally, the jQuery below should make one link (class "current-link") colored red, but for some reason, it gets stuck after one click to Link 1/2/3.

That is what I have now:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   /* Highlight "Link 1"*/
   $(".item1").click(function() {
     $(".item1").replaceWith('<a class="item1 current-link" href="#" >Link 1</a>');
     $(".item2").replaceWith('<a class="item2" href="#">Link 2</a>');
     $(".item3").replaceWith('<a class="item3" href="#">Link 3</a>');
     $(".item4").replaceWith('<a class="item4" href="#">Link 4</a>');
   });

   /* Highlight "Link 2"*/
   $(".item2").click(function() {
     $(".item1").replaceWith('<a class="item1" href="#">Link 1</a>');
     $(".item2").replaceWith('<a class="item2 current-link" href="#">Link 2</a>');
     $(".item3").replaceWith('<a class="item3" href="#">Link 3</a>');
     $(".item4").replaceWith('<a class="item4" href="#">Link 4</a>');
   });

   /* Highlight "Link 3"*/
   $(".item3").click(function() {
     $(".item1").replaceWith('<a class="item1" href="#">Link 1</a>');
     $(".item2").replaceWith('<a class="item2" href="#">Link 2</a>');
     $(".item3").replaceWith('<a class="item3 current-link" href="#">Link 3</a>');
     $(".item4").replaceWith('<a class="item4" href="#">Link 4</a>');
   });

   /* Highlight "Link 4"*/
   $(".item4").click(function() {
     $(".item1").replaceWith('<a class="item1" href="#">Link 1</a>');
     $(".item2").replaceWith('<a class="item2" href="#">Link 2</a>');
     $(".item3").replaceWith('<a class="item3" href="#">Link 3</a>');
     $(".item4").replaceWith('<a class="item4 current-link" href="#">Link 4</a>');
   });
 });
```

```css
#navbar-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}
#navbar-top ul li {
  /*float:left; */
  display: inline-block;
  font: bold 12px/12px sans-serif;
}
#navbar-top ul > li + li {
  border-left: solid 1px #374659;
}
#navbar-top a {
  /*display: block;*/
  padding: 2px 7px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: 400ms ease;
}
/*
    Necessary link style order:
 1. a:link
 2. a:visited
 3. a:hover
 4. a:active
    */

#navbar-top a:link {
  color: #374659;
  /*light grey*/
}
#navbar-top a:visited {
  color: #374659;
  /*light grey*/
}
#navbar-top a:hover {
  color: red;
  /*Slowly fade from grey to red*/
}
#navbar-top a:active {
  color: red;
}
#navbar-top a.current-link
/*Make it more specific than other selectors*/

{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="navbar-top">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="item1 current-link">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="item2">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="item3">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="item4">Link 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, you can check with `click` to set `current-link` class to different links when clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#navbar-top ul li a').on('click',function(){ 
    $('ul li a').removeClass('current-link');
    $(this).addClass('current-link');
  })
})
```

Check out this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/du6Lu4ge/5/

Hope it solves your concern.

Comment: Simple and beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("a").on("click", function() {
    $("a").removeClass("current-link");
    $(this).addClass("current-link");
  });
});
```

```css
#navbar-top
{
  position:absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;   
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}

#navbar-top ul li 
{
  /*float:left; */                          
  display: inline-block;
  font: bold 12px/12px sans-serif;
}

#navbar-top ul > li + li
{
  border-left: solid 1px #374659;
}

#navbar-top a 
{
  /*display: block;*/
  padding: 2px 7px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: 400ms ease;
}

/*
Necessary link style order:
1. a:link
2. a:visited
3. a:hover
4. a:active
*/

#navbar-top a:link
{
  color: #374659;                       /*light grey*/
}

#navbar-top a:visited
{
  color: #374659;                       /*light grey*/
}

#navbar-top a:hover
{
  color: red;                           /*Slowly fade from grey to red*/
}

#navbar-top a:active                    
{
  color: red;                   
}

#navbar-top a.current-link              /*Make it more specific than other selectors*/
{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar-top">
  <ul>              
    <li><a href="#" class="item1 current-link">Link 1</a></li>              
    <li><a href="#" class="item2">Link 2</a></li>           
    <li><a href="#" class="item3">Link 3</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#" class="item4">Link 4</a></li>                       
  </ul>
</div>
```

First, you select all the links then remove class `current-link` from it
Second, you add class `current-link` to the link that has been clicked on by using `$(this)`

use `addClass()` to add class and `removeClass()` to remove class

Comment: Your jQuery selector attaches handlers to all `<a>` elements on the page. May I suggest an edit to scope it to just the navigation (given how OP initially implemented the active class removal/swap).

Answer (score 1):

You've over done it a bit on your JS for enabling/disabling the active class `.current-link` for your menu. No need to replace all the DOM elements every time one is clicked. Typically you loop through all the navigation items, removing the unwanted class, then add the active class to the clicked navigation item.

Notice that I cached the elements of your navigation so you do not need to query the DOM every time someone clicks a link. I have also used a delegated approach to applying the click handler so we do not add a handler for every `<a>` element but rather a single click handler to the ancestor element `#navbar-top`.

```js
$( document ).ready( function () {
  
  var $navbarTop      = $( '#navbar-top' );
  var $navbarTopLinks = $navbarTop.find( 'a' );
  
  $navbarTop.on( 'click', 'a', function ( e ) {
  
    e.preventDefault();    
    $navbarTopLinks.removeClass( 'current-link' );
    $( this ).addClass( 'current-link' );
  
  } );
  
} );
```

```css
#navbar-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}
#navbar-top ul li {
  /*float:left; */
  display: inline-block;
  font: bold 12px/12px sans-serif;
}
#navbar-top ul > li + li {
  border-left: solid 1px #374659;
}
#navbar-top a {
  /*display: block;*/
  padding: 2px 7px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: 400ms ease;
}
/*
    Necessary link style order:
 1. a:link
 2. a:visited
 3. a:hover
 4. a:active
    */

#navbar-top a:link {
  color: #374659;
  /*light grey*/
}
#navbar-top a:visited {
  color: #374659;
  /*light grey*/
}
#navbar-top a:hover {
  color: red;
  /*Slowly fade from grey to red*/
}
#navbar-top a:active {
  color: red;
}
#navbar-top a.current-link
/*Make it more specific than other selectors*/

{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="navbar-top">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="current-link">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Reading your first paragraph made me laugh; I had a feeling this could be shortened. All of the answers here are worth the accepted solution IMO, but Aakash's tops it for brevity. Btw, is the additional transition inside "#navbar-top a:link" necessary when there already is one within "#navbar-top a" ?

Comment: @user2286339 Aakash's answer may be shorter but queries the DOM for `ul li a` every time you click on a navigation item vs caching those elements which would be more performant. Not to mention it will try to remove `.current-link` from any `a` that matches `ul li a` on the page - not just those inside of `#navbar-top`. Which could be an issue if there are other menus that match `ul li a` and use `.current-link` on the page. My selector only affects `a` inside of `#navbar-top`. As for `transition`, I missed the original `transition` and is not necessary - will remove from answer.

Comment: I changed the selector to '$('#navbar-top ul li a').removeClass('current-link');'  btw, thanks for the hint re caching; my site is small but anyway...